# Subcaption with margin to the left only

Tags: indentation, subfloats, subcaption

I have a subfigure and I need to move its subcaption more to the middle of the subfigure. So I want to use something like `\subfigcapmargin`, but only with the margin on the *left* side, not on the right side. What can I do?

Comment: First of all the caption should be centered by default. If it isn't, maybe the picture contains unsymmetrical white borders!? Furthermore "I have a subfigure" is much too less information for effective help. What package do you use to typeset your subfigures? Best would be a MWE.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). It is difficult to help you without a compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages. You can use the `[demo]` option with the `graphics` package so that any `\includegraphics` will be displayed as a black box and hence the images do not need to be provided with the MWE.

Comment: With no MWE, this is 'too localized' I'm afraid